# Implementing a sign in with google button between server and client

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am struggling to understand how to implement a Google login. This is currently where I am at:

The client loads a default static HTML page from the server with a login button. Once clicking the login button it redirects them to the `/login` endpoint on my server. This redirects the user to the Google login and then consent page. Once the user logs into Google it redirects them to the `/oauth2callback` endpoint on my server. The response from Google contains the token that I need to get all the user info that I need. After I get the info from Google's services I need a way to send this info to the client in a JSON format. This info will be used in order for the client to connect to a websocket endpoint on my server.

I don't understand how I can send this info to the client. The client has been redirected to pages with no GET requests made to my server so I cannot send a JSON response. I don't want the client to make an additional GET request to the server if at all possible. How can I send the data I need to to the client?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your oauth2callback redirects to, or serves a page to your user. How about setting the JSON into a cookie that your JavaScript can then parse.